# Render html template with flask in Colab

Tags: python, html, flask, google-colaboratory

I want to render html template as a separate page using Flask in Colab. Previous attempts by people indicate it is very much possible. However, none of the solutions worked for me. I either get "127.0.0.1 refused to connect" when I click on this link or some exception while running code.

Following are the solutions I tried so far:

1. Created index.html file in Google Drive. **Issue encountered**: Looks like Colab does not allow rendering html files stored in drive and display as html page for security reasons
2. Vanilla code: Index html file path is templates/index.html (stored temporarily in colab folder just for testing to get it work)

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app= Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def chat():
  return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Result**  * Serving Flask app '**main**'

- Debug mode: on
  INFO:werkzeug:WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
- Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
  INFO:werkzeug:Press CTRL+C to quit
  INFO:werkzeug: * Restarting with stat

**Issue**: 127.0.0.1 refused to connect

3. Another one

```
!pip install flask-ngrok

from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_ngrok import run_with_ngrok

app = Flask(__name__)
run_with_ngrok(app)  

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

HTML code of index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Flask App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello, Flask!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```